# Printing iframe from javascript does not work in IE on termnal server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm trying to send html inside an popup-dialog to a printer via JavaScript. I started out using this code from MDN:[Print an external page without opening it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing)

This works very well in both Chrome and IE 10 and above. But when running the same code in IE via Remote Desktop it does not work. I do not get any error-messages either.

So I changed the code and used jQuery and now the Print-dialog is showing as wanted/expected. The problem now is that in IE not only the iFrame content is printed. Now everything on the page is printed. In Chrome I get the expected print (the iFrame-content only). What is it IE dont get here:

```js
function printFrame(frameId, contentToPrint) {
                     var doc = $('#' + frameId)[0].contentWindow.document;
                     var $body = $('body', doc);

                     $body.html(contentToPrint);

                     setTimeout(function() {
                       $('#' + frameId)[0].contentWindow.focus();                       
                       $('#' + frameId)[0].contentWindow.print();
                     }, 1000);
                   };

                   $scope.printDetails = function() {
                     var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
                     oHiddFrame.id = "hiddenFrame";
                     oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
                     oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
                     oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
                     oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
                     oHiddFrame.target = "_blank";

                     document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
                     var contentToPrint = document.getElementById('eventDetails').innerHTML;
                     printFrame("hiddenFrame", contentToPrint);
                   };
```

Is the problem that the body of the iframe not gets the focus? I hope that some of you have done something similar and can tell me by just looking at my script-code can see whats missing....

As you can see the code is triggered by an ng-click that calls printDetails()-function. I'm sorry that I have not made the full code available the above snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a command that solved my issue with IE, execCommand. So I changed my code to something like this:

```js
function printFrame(frameId, contentToPrint) {
  var doc = window.frames['hiddenFrame'].document;  
  var $body = $('body', doc);

  $body.html(contentToPrint);

  setTimeout(function() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf ("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById(frameId);
        iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
    } else {
        $('#' + frameId)[0].contentWindow.focus();
        $('#' + frameId)[0].contentWindow.print();
    }
    //$('#' + frameId)[0].contentWindow.focus();
    //$('#' + frameId)[0].contentWindow.print();
  }, 1000);
};

$scope.printDetails = function() {
  var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  oHiddFrame.id = "hiddenFrame";
  oHiddFrame.name = "hiddenFrame";
  oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
  oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
  oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";  
  oHiddFrame.target = "_blank";

  document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
  var contentToPrint = document.getElementById('eventDetails').innerHTML;
  printFrame("hiddenFrame", contentToPrint);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plugin
Jquery PrintArea: https://github.com/RitsC/PrintArea

I've test it in IE9 and work on fine.

Demo : https://github.com/RitsC/PrintArea

Comment: Thanks Kelvin! I did not try your suggestion because I found another solution myself. I'll post my solution as an answer-post.